# Odoo - How to create custom global configuration file

Tags: configuration, odoo, odoo-10

I am using Odoo 10-e. I came from .net what i want to do is that i need to create my custom setting configuration file in Odoo like we have `AppSettings` file in asp.net where we set some static key values to use them in project. How to create that kind of file and how can i access that file in python code or xml files ?

Comment: Check out this link : http://ludwiktrammer.github.io/odoo/custom-settings-odoo.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a class that inherits from res.config.settings (so you can edit the record):

```py
class farmacia_pedido_config_settings(models.TransientModel):
   _inherit = 'res.config.settings'
   _name = 'farmacia.config.settings'

   lista_precios_defecto = fields.Many2one(
    'product.pricelist',
    string='Lista de precios por defecto')
```

2. Associate with the view:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
    <record id="view_farmacia_configuration" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">farmacia config settings</field>
        <field name="model">farmacia.config.settings</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Farmacia" class="oe_form_configuration">
                <header>
                    <button string="Aplicar" type="object" name="execute" class="oe_highlight"/>
                    <button string="Cancelar" type="object" name="cancel" class="oe_link"/>
                </header>

                <field name="lista_precios_defecto" class="oe_inline"/>

                </group>
                </form>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="action_farmacia_configuration" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Farmacia</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">farmacia.config.settings</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form</field>
        <field name="target">inline</field>
    </record>

    <menuitem id="menu_farmacia_config" name="Farmacia" parent="base.menu_config"
        sequence="3" action="action_farmacia_configuration"/>

</data>
</openerp>
```

3. Save in a file accessing via python (this is uglier)

```py
config = ConfigParser()
your_file = os.getenv("HOME")+os.path.sep+"your_file.conf"
if os.path.isfile(your_file):
    config.read(your_file)
else:
    raise models.except_orm(
        'Error',
        "File not found " + os.getcwd())
```